# How to keep vertical scrollbar always present on the body?

Tags: html, scrollbar

```
$("#btnGall").click(function() {
    $('#home,#vid,#story,#con').hide();
    $('#gall').slideDown('slow');
});
```

After the first line the screen is almost empty and scrollbar disappears, moving the rest of the page to the right.
After the second line - scrollbar reappears, and again shift whole of the page.
How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [`overflow-y`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow) to html.

```
html { overflow-y: scroll }
```

If I recall, applying that to body will cause double scrollbars on IE.

Edit: [Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5UTbS/1/).

Comment: Of course, I just must wait then minutes, It's not possible earlier.